# How can i update excisting document with merging another one in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to update a document with another document has same schema and belong to same entity.
Its possible to adding new sensors objects in sensors array or just there will be new value records for next measurements.

**excisting document**

```
  "deviceName": "test",
  "isActive": true,
  "sensors": [{
      "id": "sgfgssfgs",
      "values": {
        "1": 232,
        "2": 3434,
        "3": 5454
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "fgffgf",
      "values": {
        "1": 232,
        "2": 3434,
        "3": 5454
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**new document i want to use for merging**

```
{
  "deviceName": "test",
  "isActive": true,
  "sensors": [{
      "id": "sgfgssfgs",
      "values": {
        "4": 5454
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "fgffgf",
      "values": {
        "4": 5454
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**and its the result which i want to see**

```
{
  "deviceName": "test",
  "isActive": true,
  "sensors": [{
      "id": "sgfgssfgs",
      "values": {
        "1": 232,
        "2": 3434,
        "3": 5454,
        "4": 5454
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "fgffgf",
      "values": {
        "1": 232,
        "2": 3434,
        "3": 5454,
        "4": 5454
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mongodb version: 3.6 +

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$sensors"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        deviceName: "$deviceName",
        sensor: "$sensors.id",

      },
      isActive: {
        $first: "$isActive"
      },
      values: {
        $mergeObjects: "$sensors.values"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.deviceName",
      isActive: {
        $first: "$isActive"
      },
      sensors: {
        $push: {
          id: "$_id.sensor",
          values: "$values",

        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      deviceName: "$_id",
      isActive: 1,
      sensors: 1,
      _id: 0,

    }
  }
])
```

you can test here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/XbavgR6w2lA